# Laravel Breeze: how to login after unhashing password

Tags: laravel, breeze

I am new to Laravel and even newer to Breeze. Breeze has been very helpful. From out of the box, Breeze works as intended: I can make a new user, and login to the dashboard.

However, every time I unhash the password, inside of

app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController.php

app\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest.php

and finally
the current migration causes an error.

I can create an account,  and see all the values inside of my database, but whenever I try and login I get this: "These credentials do not match our records." Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: EDIT: I even went into the Controllers folder, and went into all the files, specifically PasswordController.php and NewPasswordController.php and deleted any Hash tags. Even after creating a new account and going into the profile section of Breeze, if I try to update and change my password, I get an error stating: The password is Incorrect

Comment: So I am not sure how (or why) you are unhashing the password. Authentication usually takes the user input password and hashes it, it then checks the hashed password vs the hashed password stored in the DB. So only hashed passwords are saved in the DB for security purposes.

Comment: I simply removed any make::Hash or bcrypt properties from primarily the users and models folders. For my project, hashing the passwords will be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: Does Breeze support non-hashable passwords? Or will it only work with the secure passwords?

Comment: I would highly recommend you rethink. Hashing passwords is critical for security. Without hashing, your users security could be compromised easily.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. When you say unhashing the password, do you mean saving the actual password text to database? You dont want that for security reasons